# Jquery Select 2 not showing selected value with trigger change

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-select2

iam use Select2 -ver 4.0.12
but dont Select 2 not showing selected value and trigger event change
this my code .i think Select2 -ver 4.0.12  is bug

```
  $("#Misson_Type").select2({
        width: '290px',
        dropdownParent: $("#modMission"),
        
    });

  $('body').on('click', 'a[id^="rowedit-"]', function (e) {
          $('#Misson_Type').val('9');
          $('#Misson_Type').trigger('change');  
   })

     <div class="col-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Misson_Type,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MissonType, new { @class = "form-control select2" })
```

iam us ethis code but dont work

```
   $('#Misson_Type option').eq('9').prop('selected',true);
   $("#Misson_Type").trigger("change");
```

Comment: It's better for you to set the value of the select instead of changing the selected attribute

Comment: What do you mean about "dont work", is there any error when you use F12 developer tools to check it? Based on your code, I try to create a sample (remove the select2 dropdownParent option: `dropdownParent: $("#modMission"),`), the code works well on my side. So, you can try to remove this option in the select2 function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam  use this code
My problem was solved

```
   $("#Misson_Type").select2({
        width: '150px',
        dropdownParent: $('#modMission .modal-content')
    });
```